# Exact match in Alfresco FTS with special characters

Tags: full-text-search, match, alfresco

I'm trying to perform a query in Alfresco 5.2.7, in Alfresco FTS language using the API, to highlight some results. As long as I don't have special characters, everything is fine. The issue comes when I try to perform a query to search (in exact match) the word "name?". I can't escape the question mark to be able to force the query to search the question mark along with the whole word. The results in the highlighting array are always without the special characters.
This is my functional query:

```
  {
  "query": {
    "language": "afts",
    "query": "(content:\"content\") AND TYPE:\"cm:content\""
  },
  "paging": {
    "maxItems": 100,
    "skipCount": 0
  },

  "scope": {
    "locations": "nodes"
  },

"highlight": {
    "snippetCount":10,
    "mergeContiguous": true,
      "fields": [
          {
              "field": "cm:content"
          }

     ]

  }

}
```

And this is the result: note the highlighted word is between  tag.

```
{
  "list": {
    "pagination": {
      "count": 1,
      "hasMoreItems": false,
      "totalItems": 1,
      "skipCount": 0,
      "maxItems": 100
    },
    "context": {},
    "entries": [
      {
        "entry": {
          "isFile": true,
          "createdByUser": {
            "id": "admin",
            "displayName": "Administrator"
          },
          "modifiedAt": "2021-01-15T15:29:03.275+0000",
          "nodeType": "miims:contenytrOPI",
          "content": {
            "mimeType": "text/html",
            "mimeTypeName": "HTML",
            "sizeInBytes": 489,
            "encoding": "UTF-8"
          },
          "parentId": "8b7c5c54-293b-4c95-a850-824efd402667",
          "createdAt": "2020-12-22T08:12:12.369+0000",
          "isFolder": false,
          "search": {
            "score": 0.21531886,
            "highlight": [
              {
                "field": "cm:content",
                "snippets": [
                  "\n\n\n2??3pppusa\n2 <em>content</em>?"
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          "modifiedByUser": {
            "id": "admin",
            "displayName": "Administrator"
          },
          "name": "nodeName",
          "location": "nodes",
          "id": "b7811537-b3af-47bf-9f9c-c4bfaa43832a"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The question is simple: how to force FTS to ignore special characters like "?" or "*" and search those characters in a literal way? I have tried with ? or /? in the query, with no results.

Answer (score 1):

This should be pretty straight forward by escaping the special character through a backslash.

https://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/concepts/rm-searchsyntax-escaping.html
https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html#Escaping_Special_Characters

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to escape it using the backslash before posting the question, but that doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. A screenshot of what?.

Comment: Your query not working, for example from Node Browser?

Comment: No, it's not. I'm afraid FTS is doing something weird behind the scenes.